# overset text over equal sign in in an Align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, align

Look at the following example

```
\begin{align}
     & x \\
     \overset{\text{some long explanation}}= & foo \\
     & = bar
\end{align}
```

what is the best way to get the equal signs aligned? Now I have seen different solution such as adding `\overset{\hphantom{\ţext{some long explanation}}}=` to the beginning of every line, but I don't really think that is the best solution.
Any better ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I guess what i am actually after is

1. aligning the first column of the align environment right
2. aligning the equal sign under the overset text right

Comment: Please correct your current code snippet, since I assume you're after some horizontal alignment. You just mention "align" but provide a horizontally set `align`. At the moment it's not entire clear what you're after.

Comment: yes. I guess what you mean where the missing \\s?

Comment: If you modify `\mathclap` in Herbert's answer to `\mathllap`, you get something more in line with what you're after. If this is still not the case, could you include an ASCII art (or some other drawing/image) of the exact alignment you're after?

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x & \\
    &\overset{\mathclap{\strut\text{some long explanation}}}= foo\\
    & = bar
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this leads to *some long text* floating into the formula after the equal sign

Comment: I find `\strut` to be unrelated with the problem, plus it creates some unwanted vertical space. `\mathclap` alone seems to be sufficient to solve the issue.

Comment: You only want to ignore the left overlapping part of the _some long text_ for the `align` environment while properly aligning the following text _foo_ according to standard math-alignment rules. This has not been answered here.

Comment: Is there any way to get this working without importing `mathtools`? The latter kind of destroys my over-/underbraces, so that is not really an option.

Answer (score 7):

you say you don't want to repeat "some long explanation", but there really isn't any better way to do it that i know of.

is this what you're after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 x &\overset{\text{some long explanation}}= foo \\
   &\overset{\phantom{\text{some long explanation}}}= bar
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, but it is not very neat.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following `\alignedoverset` macro, which preserves the spacing and aligns the left edge of the second argument?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, calc}
\newlength\oversetwidth
\newlength\underwidth
\newcommand\alignedoverset[2]{
  % #1 = over
  % #2 = under
  \settowidth\oversetwidth{$\overset{#1}{#2}$}
  \settowidth\underwidth{$#2$}
  \setlength\oversetwidth{\oversetwidth-\underwidth}
  \hspace{.5\oversetwidth}
  &
  \settowidth\oversetwidth{$\overset{#1}{#2}$}
  \settowidth\underwidth{$#2$}
  \setlength\oversetwidth{\oversetwidth-\underwidth}
  \hspace{-.5\oversetwidth}
  \overset{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x + 2 \alignedoverset{\text{some long explanation}}{\geq} foo \\
  & = bar
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems to break if the second argument is longer than the first, but in that case it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much hacky you want to be, you can use the not so dirty trick in the first solution, the *very* dirty trick in the second solution.

I'd definitely prefer the third solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% for the first solution
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle{}#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% for the second solution
\newcommand{\CEN}[1]{%
  \multispan{1}\hfill$\displaystyle{}#1$\hfill
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
x & \Cen{2}{{}\overset{\text{some long explanation}}={}} && foo \\
  & \Cen{2}{{}={}}                                       && bar
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
x & \CEN{\overset{\text{some long explanation}}=} && foo \\
  & \CEN{=}                                       && bar
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
x &= foo &\qquad& \text{(some long explanation)} \\
  &= bar
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]