# Center \leq, \geq, = with different text above

Tags: align

I am typesetting some mathematical equations using `\begin{align*}` environment. Hopefully to make the steps clear I am adding text above `=, \leq, \geq` but I am having troubles with aligning them e.g.:

```
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2
\overset{\text{some text}}=& 2y^3 \leq\\
\overset{\text{some longer text}}\leq& 3z
\end{align*}
```

The result is, that the `\leq` is not centered with `=` sign above. Is there a neat way to solve this? In some different cases I am using this approach:

```
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2
\overset{\text{some text}}=& 2y^3 \leq\\
\overset{\phantom{\text{some text}}}\leq& 3z
\end{align*}
```

But I don't think that adding some phantom characters to the first example would be a good way how to do it.

Comment: Long justifications are better placed on the side.

Comment: I agree with @egreg writing on top of relations etc is considered bad style in writing, and should be reformulated instead. Some of this may be fine on a blackboard, but not in print. Also remember `\intertext{...}` and its cousin `\shortintertext{...}` from `mathtools`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure it out differently, maybe discuss it with professor for whom I write it. But sometimes it is something like `from def 3.11(ii)` in my language "only" `z def 3.11(ii)`, so I might stick to it form time to time. But I guess "long justification" can stand for two and more characters sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Center a column in align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70365/16967) and [overset text over equal sign in in an Align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40337/16967)

Comment: @quapka: I've just added 2 solutions to the answers in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/center-a-column-in-align They allow for the use of the `align`environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution proposes use of `makebox` where adjustment of width is possible for one's need.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paper size={10cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

{\bf OP:}

\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2
\overset{\text{some text}}=& 2y^3 \leq\\
\overset{\text{some longer text}}\leq& 3z
\end{align*}


{\bf Use of makebox:}

\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2
\makebox[3cm][c]{$\overset{\text{some text}} = $}              &2y^3 \leq\\
\makebox[3cm][c]{$\overset{\text{some longe text}} \leq$}  &   3z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had started with makebox but I was getting lots of errors so I gave up :-( I now see it was simple: I was missing the $ inside the makebox. I like this solution myself. I am going to upvote it!

Comment: @FionaSmith -- I was thinking of array, but your OP mentioned that and that forced me to think what else ...

Comment: How to create a box with the same width of an other box? Instead of hardcoding the `3cm` I'd like to do something like: `\makebox[\getWidthOf{\overset{\text{some long text}}\leq}][x]{$\overset{\text{some text}}\leq$}` to have the symbol with the shorter text take *exactly* the same space as the symbol with the longer text (and nothing more).

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Please check here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18576/34618. If this does not help, then you need to ask a new question since this is closed, not available of posting any.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is quite what you want, but you could use a `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{r c l}
$x_1 + x_2$ & $ \overset{\text{some text}}=           $ & $2y^3 \leq$ \\
            & $ \overset{\text{some longer text}}\leq $ & $3z$
\end{tabular}
```

You then get them centred one above the other, but there is extra space around the = in the first line.

Or, as egreg suggests, `array`

```
$
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}
x_1 + x_2 & \overset{\text{some text}}=            & 2y^3 \leq \\
            &  \overset{\text{some longer text}}\leq  & 3z
\end{array}
$
```

Comment: Well although this would done the job It does not seem like a good solution for almost "two times a page" use. Still thanks, but I'll probably go with @egreg advice. But I might use it in some cases.

Comment: Since this is math, an `array` would be better, with `\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}` (requires also the `array` package).

Comment: maybe what you want is something like `dcases` - see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics ?

Comment: @egreg I have added an example. I've not used `array` before and in the example I was looking at I was very confused by the whole string of `@{}r@{}` etc and didn't want to spend time looking it up! Since you provided the correct code, I've updated my example above.

Comment: With `@{}` we remove the intercolumn space; the `>{{}}c<{{}}` construction adds empty atoms around the relation symbols in the `c` column so the spacing will be correct.