# How do I avoid eqnarray?

Tags: equations, align

We have been told to [avoid `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) and use `align` instead.

The output of `eqnarray` here:

```
\newcommand{\Prob}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\tp}{\operatorname{tp}}
\newcommand{\fp}{\operatorname{fp}}
\newcommand{\fn}{\operatorname{fn}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\operatorname{tn}}
\newcommand{\Act}{\operatorname{Actual}}
\newcommand{\Pre}{\operatorname{Predicted}}
\newcommand{\Ar}{\operatorname{Accuracy}}
\newcommand{\Ps}{\operatorname{Precision}}
\newcommand{\Rc}{\operatorname{Recall}}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Ar =& \Prob(\Act=\Pre)  &= \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc =& \Prob(\Pre=1|\Act=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps =& \Prob(\Act=1|\Pre=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

is imperfect:

[image: latex output]

but I cannot get even that with either `align` or `alignat`...

Comment: `eqnarray` does not support anything other than two `&` in a line, your first example just generates errors????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: nope. no errors.

Comment: `align` produces different output than `eqnarray` by design. The spacing in `eqnarray` is basically wrong. the spacing around `=` should not change just because the following line is aligned. `eqnarray` gives it the spacing from `tabular` more or less.

Comment: I think perhaps you want `alignat`: `\begin{alignat*}{3}
   foo &= bar &&= baz \\
foobar &= barquux &&= bazzot
\end{alignat*}`.  Please include an image of the output that you desire.

Comment: @sds that is why you should always provide a complete document. You must have loaded a package that redefines `eqnarray` as the one defined in the latex format will generate an error on that input. so cannot guess what your output looks like

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: please see edit. thanks for you attention, sorry about poor first version.

Comment: @sds oh so only two `&` taht's a highly hmm "inventive" use of `eqnarray` :-) it absolutely was never designed to be used like that, the central column is supposed to be used for `=` or other operator on which to align, not whole subterms!. Also your example _still_ is not a document that people can run.

Comment: @sds i updated my answer to match the new example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your updated example code, I actually suggest that you use an `array` environment, with the value of `\arraystretch` increased to mimic a displaymath setting.

Two additional suggestions: (i) for the "conditioning operator", use `\mid` instead of `|` -- you'll get much better spacing; (ii) most of the items you've declared as math operators are, as far as I can tell, simple text strings; I would use `\textrm` instead of `\operatorname` in the definitions of `\tp`, `\fp`, etc.

The following screenshot shows the outputs of the `array` and `eqnarray*` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\tp}{\textnormal{tp}}
\newcommand{\fp}{\textnormal{fp}}
\newcommand{\fn}{\textnormal{fn}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\textnormal{tn}}
\newcommand{\Act}{\textnormal{Actual}}
\newcommand{\Pre}{\textnormal{Predicted}}
\newcommand{\Ar}{\textnormal{Accuracy}}
\newcommand{\Ps}{\textnormal{Precision}}
\newcommand{\Rc}{\textnormal{Recall}}
\begin{document}
Output of \texttt{array}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} c @{{}={}} l} % "{}={}" is inserted in the intercolumn spaces
  \Ar & \Prob(\Act=\Pre)          & \dfrac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc & \Prob(\Pre=1\mid \Act=1)  & \dfrac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps & \Prob(\Act=1\mid \Pre=1)  & \dfrac{\tp}{\tp+\fp} \\
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip
Output of \texttt{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Ar =& \Prob(\Act=\Pre)          &= \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc =& \Prob(\Pre=1\mid \Act=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps =& \Prob(\Act=1\mid \Pre=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
foo &=& bar &=& baz \\
foobar &=& barquux &=& bazzot
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

the standard `eqnarray` only takes two `&`

Using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
foo &= bar &&= baz \\
foobar &= barquux &&= bazzot
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

With the updated example, made into a complete document, the results are

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Prob}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\tp}{\operatorname{tp}}
\newcommand{\fp}{\operatorname{fp}}
\newcommand{\fn}{\operatorname{fn}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\operatorname{tn}}
\newcommand{\Act}{\operatorname{Actual}}
\newcommand{\Pre}{\operatorname{Predicted}}
\newcommand{\Ar}{\operatorname{Accuracy}}
\newcommand{\Ps}{\operatorname{Precision}}
\newcommand{\Rc}{\operatorname{Recall}}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Ar =& \Prob(\Act=\Pre)  &= \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc =& \Prob(\Pre=1|\Act=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps =& \Prob(\Act=1|\Pre=1)  &= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \Ar &= \Prob(\Act=\Pre)  &&= \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc &= \Prob(\Pre=1|\Act=1)  &&= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps &= \Prob(\Act=1|\Pre=1)  &&= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{alignat*}



\end{document}
```

Note how `align` gives the `=` on the longest entry just the space normally given to `=` and just adds space as necessary to align. `eqalign` always pads the central column with additional space causing asymmetric  spacing around `=` on all rows.

Comment: thanks! how do I make the center column (bar/barquux) centered?

Comment: @sds don't: it disturbs the equation, but if you really want to, see egreg's answer. which is same apart from a centering trick.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an application of a macro I showed in [Aligning equations with left and right comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209645/aligning-equations-with-left-and-right-comment) (you find there explanations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\Prob}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\tp}{\mathrm{tp}}
\newcommand{\fp}{\mathrm{fp}}
\newcommand{\fn}{\mathrm{fn}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\mathrm{tn}}
\newcommand{\Act}{\mathrm{Actual}}
\newcommand{\Pre}{\mathrm{Predicted}}
\newcommand{\Ar}{\mathrm{Accuracy}}
\newcommand{\Ps}{\mathrm{Precision}}
\newcommand{\Rc}{\mathrm{Recall}}

% the magic trick, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \Ar ={}& \Cen{2}{\Prob(\Act=\Pre)}        &&= \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc ={}& \Cen{2}{\Prob(\Pre=1\mid\Act=1)} &&= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps ={}& \Cen{2}{\Prob(\Act=1\mid\Pre=1)} &&= \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

We need two groups of left-right columns, with no space between them, so I use `alignat` (the `alignat*` version will not print numbers). In the column we want centered, which is the second, I enclose the material as the second argument to `\Cen` (the first argument is the column number). We need `&&=` because the last column must be left aligned.

[image]

Note that the only real operator name is `\Prob`, the other symbols are just variables, so they should be defined with `\mathrm`. Note also `\mid` instead of `|`, which gives a better spacing.

Whether to center the second column is a judgment question; in my document I'd simply use `gather` or `align` to put the three equations flush left.

```
\begin{gather}
  \Ar = \Prob(\Act=\Pre) = \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
  \Rc = \Prob(\Pre=1\mid\Act=1) = \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
  \Ps = \Prob(\Act=1\mid\Pre=1) = \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
&  \Ar = \Prob(\Act=\Pre) = \frac{\tp+\tn}{N} \\
&  \Rc = \Prob(\Pre=1\mid\Act=1) = \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fn} \\
&  \Ps = \Prob(\Act=1\mid\Pre=1) = \frac{\tp}{\tp+\fp}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can centre the middle column with the `makebox` or the `eqparbox` packages. The eqparbox commands use a tag that makes all boxes that use that tag have width equal to the largest width of boxes; by default, their contents is centred in the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makebox}
```

\usepackage{eqparbox}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
foo &= \makebox*{$ barquux $} {$ bar $}&&= baz \\
foobar &= barquux &&= bazzot
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
foo &= \eqmakebox[Col]{$ bar$} &&= baz \\
foobar &= \eqmakebox[Col]{$ barquux $} &&= bazzot
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]