# Flush Text to the Left in an Unaligned Centered Equation

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

I am looking for a way to write several centered equations with a left-aligned text on each line. In other words, I would like to mix the functionality of `flalign` with `gather` (so the first column would be flushed left, while the second column would be centered), but I have not found a way to do so. Please help.

Comment: Could we have a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Are the equations to be numbered?  Are the centered equations "aligned" to some tab, or are each of the equations individually centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had asked in a comment whether the centered equations were *also* aligned, since the approach differs in that case.  So here, I show it using both `equation` and `align` environments, with my macro `\addlefttext[textwidth-fraction]{left text}{equation}`.

If using it with the `equation` environment, there is no need for the optional argument and one should enclose the full equation as the second mandatory argument.

With the `align` environment, there is some manual tuning, as one can only enclose the left-most field of the aligned equations as the second mandatory argument of `\addlefttext`.  This means that the required leftward shift will depend on the eventual location of that left most `align` field.

The optional argument provides the fraction of `\textwidth` to shift the label leftward (relative to the right end of the first `align` field).  The bad news is therefore, that the optional argument must be tuned to the particular `align` environment.  However, the good news is that the tuned fraction is the same for each row of the align environment.

EDITED to remove need for `ifthen` package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath,lipsum}
\newcommand\addlefttext[3][-1]{%
  \def\stacktype{L}\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifdim#1pt<0pt\relax%
    \def\stackalignment{c}%
    \stackon[0pt]{$\displaystyle#3$}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{#2}}%
  \else%
    \def\stackalignment{r}%
    \stackon[0pt]{$\displaystyle#3$}{\makebox[#1\textwidth][l]{#2}}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\addlefttext{My text}{y = mx + b}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\addlefttext{My other text}{E = mc^2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
\addlefttext[.452]{My text}{y} &= mx + b\\
\addlefttext[.452]{My other text}{E} &= mc^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is suitable for some other situations I did not put in the original question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variant of my answer to [Aligning equations with left and right comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209645/aligning-equations-with-left-and-right-comment), adapted to `flalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Straight line} & \Cen{3}{y=mx+q}      && \\
&\text{Parabola}      & \Cen{3}{y=ax^2+bx+c} &&
\end{flalign}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]