# Alignat environment changes its behaviour in one document

Tags: amsmath, books, alignat

I have the following problem: I am writing my PhD and the alignat environment changes the behaviour during the document. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{A}
        This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width.

        \begin{alignat}{3}
            & \big\{\phi_{B^\prime}(v) | \mbox{$v \in V$ is a leaf of $G$}\big\}
                && = \big\{b \in B | \iota(b) \not\equiv d \mod d\big\}\\
            \intertext{and}
            & \big\{\phi_{B^\prime}(v) | \mbox{$v \in V$ is not a leaf of $G$}\big\}
                && = \big\{b \in B | \iota(b) \equiv d \mod d\big\}.
        \end{alignat}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{B}
        This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width.

        \begin{alignat}{3}
            & \big\{\phi_{B^\prime}(v) | \mbox{$v \in V$ is a leaf of $G$}\big\}
                && = \big\{b \in B | \iota(b) \not\equiv d \mod d\big\}\\
            \intertext{and}
            & \big\{\phi_{B^\prime}(v) | \mbox{$v \in V$ is not a leaf of $G$}\big\}
                && = \big\{b \in B | \iota(b) \equiv d \mod d\big\}.
        \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

After using `\mainmatter` the alignat environment changes its behaviour. I tried to use `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, but it did not help.

Is it a bug? Or do I something wrong?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Best regards,
T

Comment: Other than `(1)` vs `(1.1)` I do not see any difference

Comment: `\mainmatter` switches chapter counting on, i.e. `\frontmatter` will use unnumbered chapters, regardless, whether `\chapter` or `\chapter*` is used. As such, the `equation` number is now `(1.1)` (wider than before)

Comment: No, the alignments around the “=” are in the second case wrong (before “=” is additional space and the line width is exceeded (without yielding a warning)).

Comment: From `book.cls`: `\renewcommand\theequation
  {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}` -- i.e. as long as the chapter number is zero, it will not be prepended to the `equation` number, i.e. `\mainmatter` increases the counter output and that's to wide for `alignat`

Comment: There's certainly a issue with `\frontmatter` and the `fleqn` option, which seems to be triggered when the equation is rather wide.

Comment: Thank you, I tried now to remove the fleqn option and than all is OK. So there is no problem with the chapter number in this concrete case. However, I would like to use the fleqn option due to other equations.

Comment: this problem was noted in 1996, and allegedly fixed in the 1997 release of `amsmath`; it is not a problem when used with an ams document class, but with `[12pt]{book}` it reappears.  it has been re-posted to the "live" `amsmath` bugs list.  thank you for the reliably working example.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a mainmatter/frontmatter issue. But due to the larger number the equation is a bit too long for the line and then alignat pushes the number in the margin. I don't know if it is intended or a bug or simply can't be avoided. You probably will have to shorten your equation.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A}
        This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width.

        \begin{alignat}{3}
            &a
                && = b\\            
        \end{alignat}

        \begin{alignat}{3}                         
            &a
                && = btests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width\\                
        \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but in the first case there (in my example) there is enough space. The problem is the unnecessary free space before “=” in the second case. The numbers of equations are usually on a new line if the expression is too long.

Comment: You are saying that there is enough space, but obviously latex doesn't. If I shorten both equations a bit the numbers are again in the text (not using fleqn helps too).

Comment: definitely a bug.  see comment on original question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug of `alignat` when `fleqn` is active and the equation is too wide.

I can offer you a workaround (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Lft}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{A}

This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a 
string which tests the text width.
\begin{align}
  \Lft{1}{\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}}
  & = \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \not\equiv d \mod d\bigr\}
\intertext{and}
  \Lft{1}{\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is not a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}}
  & = \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \equiv d \mod d\bigr\}.
\end{align}

\mainmatter

\chapter{B}

This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a 
string which tests the text width.
\begin{align}
  \Lft{1}{\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}}
  & = \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \not\equiv d \mod d\bigr\}
\intertext{and}
  \Lft{1}{\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is not a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}}
  & = \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \equiv d \mod d\bigr\}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I used `oneside` just in order to show the pages side by side.

[image]

On the other hand, I'd simply use `gather` for this case, but of course two `equation` environments would do as well (and even better).

```
This is a string which tests the text width. This is a string which tests the text width. This is a
string which tests the text width.
\begin{equation}
\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}
= \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \not\equiv d \mod d\bigr\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\bigl\{\phi_{B'}(v) \mid \text{$v \in V$ is not a leaf of $G$}\bigr\}
= \bigl\{b \in B \mid \iota(b) \equiv d \mod d\bigr\}.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! You are right that it looks better with the equation environment. However, I have the same problem on many places of my PhD thesis and thus I use the first solution as well.