# How to write the general optimization problem?

Tags: align, ieeetran, arrays, alignat

I want to write the optimization problem.

My code is:

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
    & \underset{\framebox(100,10){}}{\text{minimize}}   & \quad & \framebox(100,10){}\\
    & \text{subject to}                                 &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \max_{i=1,\ldots,l+m+n} \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \min_{i \in \mathbb{R}} \framebox(100,10){}.
\end{alignat}
```

The result is:
[image]

However, I want to make the problem like this:
[image]

1. minimize and subject to is aligned at center.
2. constraints are aligned at left (except for subscript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `mathtools` you have a command `\mathclap{<formula>}` that can help you here. It centeres the `<formula>` but does not occupy any space. You can use that to center the subscript. To get a space between the `\max` and the following box you can insert `\rule{15pt}{0pt}`, but I like it better without. The text can be centered with `\makebox` in the same way as your `\framebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    & \underset{\framebox(100,10){}}{\text{minimize}}   & \quad & \framebox(100,10){}\\
    & \makebox(100,10){subject to}                      &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
    &                                                   &       & {\max_{\mathclap{i=1,\ldots,l+m+n}}\framebox(100,10){}},\\
    &                                                   &       & {\min_{i \in \mathbb{R}} \framebox(100,10){}}.
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `\mathclap{\text{some text}}` with the simpler `\clap{some text}`.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that should do. I can actually use `\text` for the first one and `\makebox` for the second (which also removes the slightly anoying `\rule`). I have updated.

Comment: I know now the command "mathclap". By the way, can you start the frarmebox in $(6)$ at the end of $i=1,\ldots,l+m+n$?

Comment: @Danny_Kim yes, add `\rule{15pt}{0pt}` before the framebox. It is just a distnace of 15pt, which seems to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427

You can use `\opt{maximize}` in case this is the optimization problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\opt}{me{_}}{%
  \Cen{1}{\operatorname*{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\subjectto}{}{\Cen{1}{\textnormal{subject to}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\opt{minimize}_{\framebox(100,10){}} && \quad & \framebox(100,10){}\\
\subjectto                           &&       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
                                     &&       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
                                     &&       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
                                     &&       & \framebox(100,10){},\\
                                     &&       & \max_{i=1,\ldots,l+m+n} \framebox(100,10){},\\
                                     &&       & \min_{i \in \mathbb{R}} \framebox(100,10){}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]