# Aligned words with math mode

Tags: equations, align

How to align the words "direção x", "direção y" with the word "continuidade"?

[image]

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:mx}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \left(u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
+ v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial 
x} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)
\hspace{8ex}
\mbox{direção x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:my}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = - \left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
+ v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial 
y} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}\right)
\hspace{8ex}
\mbox{direção y}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:cm}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0
\hspace{8ex}\mbox{continuidade}
\end{equation}
```

Edit:I want align just the words: "direção x", "direção y" and "continuidade". The equations can stay in the same position as in the figure.

Comment: Are you aware of the align environment? Perhaps you might want to make your question more specific, i.e. indicate whether you wish the alignment of the equations as shown in your post, or want to align the = signs.

Comment: I want align just the words: "direção x", "direção y", "continuidade". The equations can stay in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `align` uses r/l alignments, there was still a little manual fiddling to quasi-center the bottom equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:mx}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \left(u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
+ v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial 
x} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)
&\hspace{8ex}
\mbox{direção x}
\\\label{eq:my}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = - \left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
+ v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial 
y} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2} + 
\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}\right)
&\hspace{8ex}
\mbox{direção y}
\\\label{eq:cm}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0
\hspace{17.8ex}&\hspace{8ex}\mbox{continuidade}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a trick similar to the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pder}[3][]{%
  \frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colwidth@}[1]{%
  \ifcase\expandafter#1\maxcolumn@widths\fi
}
\newcommand{\Cen}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \kern-\colwidth@{1}%
      \makebox[\dimexpr\colwidth@{1}+\colwidth@{2}]{$\displaystyle#1$}%
    }%
  \fi&
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:mx}
\pder{u}{t} &= - \left(u\pder{u}{x} + v\pder{u}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{x} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{u}{x} + \pder[2]{u}{y}\right)
&&
\text{direção $x$}
\\
\label{eq:my}
\pder{v}{t} &= - \left(u\pder{v}{x} + v\pder{v}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{y} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{v}{x} + \pder[2]{v}{y}\right)
&&
\text{direção $y$}
\\
\label{eq:cm}
\Cen{\pder{u}{x} + \pder{v}{y} = 0}
&&\text{continuidade}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative, without centering the last line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pder}[3][]{%
  \frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:mx}
\pder{u}{t} &= - \left(u\pder{u}{x} + v\pder{u}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{x} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{u}{x} + \pder[2]{u}{y}\right)
&&
\text{direção $x$}
\\
\label{eq:my}
\pder{v}{t} &= - \left(u\pder{v}{x} + v\pder{v}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{y} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{v}{x} + \pder[2]{v}{y}\right)
&&
\text{direção $y$}
\\
\label{eq:cm}
\pder{u}{x} &+ \pder{v}{y} = 0
&&\text{continuidade}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative approach is with `IEEEeqnarray` of `IEEEtrantools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\pder}[3][]{%
  \frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl'l}
\label{eq:mx}
\pder{u}{t} &=& - \left(u\pder{u}{x} + v\pder{u}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{x} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{u}{x} + \pder[2]{u}{y}\right)
&
\text{direção $x$}
\\
\label{eq:my}
\pder{v}{t} &=& - \left(u\pder{v}{x} + v\pder{v}{y}\right) - \pder{P}{y} + 
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\pder[2]{v}{x} + \pder[2]{v}{y}\right)
&
\text{direção $y$}
\\
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{c}{\pder{u}{x} + \pder{v}{y} = 0}
&\text{continuidade}
\label{eq:cm}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose these variants based on `flalign`:

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:mx}
 & & \diffp{u}{t}= - \left(u\diffp{u}{x} + v\diffp{u}{y}\right)& - \diffp{P}{x} +
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\diffp[2]{u}{x} + \diffp[2]{u}{y}\right)
&&
\text{\small direção $x$} \\[0.5ex]
\label{eq:my}
 & & \diffp{v}{t}= - \left(u\diffp{v}{x} + v\diffp{v}{y}\right) &- \diffp{P}{y} +
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\diffp[2]{v}{x} + \diffp[2]{v}{y}\right)
&&
\text{\small direção $y$} \\[0.5ex]
\label{eq:cm}
 & & \diffp{u}{x}& + \diffp{v}{y} = 0
& &\text{\small continuidade}
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:mx}
 & & \diffp{u}{t}= - \left(u\diffp{u}{x} + v\diffp{u}{y}\right)& - \diffp{P}{x} +
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\diffp[2]{u}{x} + \diffp[2]{u}{y}\right)
&
\text{\small direção $x$}& \\[0.5ex]
\label{eq:my}
 & & \diffp{v}{t}= - \left(u\diffp{v}{x} + v\diffp{v}{y}\right) &- \diffp{P}{y} +
\frac{1}{Re}\left(\diffp[2]{v}{x} + \diffp[2]{v}{y}\right)
&
\text{\small direção $y$}& \\[0.5ex]
\label{eq:cm}
 & & \diffp{u}{x}& + \diffp{v}{y} = 0
&\text{\small continuidade} &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compile the following at least twice on the first go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =
    - \left(u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
    + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}
    + \frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
    + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)$} &&&
  \text{direção $x$} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = 
    - \left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
    + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} 
    + \frac{1}{Re}\left(\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2} 
    + \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}\right)$} &&&
  \text{direção $y$} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
    + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$} &&&
  \text{continuidade}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The package [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) ensures that all `\eqmakebox[<tag>]` with the same `<tag>` have the same *maximum* width. The default is to `c`entre the content within these boxes, although you can change that `align`ment (`\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]`).

Comment: This relies on the fact that `u` and `v` have the same width; with `w` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand...

Comment: Try replacing the first `\partial u` with `\partial uuuuu` and you'll see what I mean; but already `\partial w` shows the issue.

Comment: @egreg: I know you're referencing the fact that the first two equations currently line up at the `=`, but that's not a requirement in the question. The OP explicitly mentions that "[the] equations can stay in the same position as in the figure.". So, alignment around `=` was explicitly avoided in my answer (not the use of `&&&`...