# flalign - aligning terms in two lined equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, flalign

Currently the code below produces the following:
[image]

The words on the left hand side are fine (i.e. I want them aligned to the left margin) and so are the equation numbers (i.e. I want them aligned to the right margin). However, I would like the terms in the middle $\xi$ and $\sigma$ to be centred relative to each other so the formulation looks neater.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,default]{amsart}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}\refstepcounter{equation}
\text{Gas injection:}    &&
    \xi = Y_i,  &&
    \sigma = \left( \dfrac{\bar{s}_{\textrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi,      &&  \tag{\theequation $a$-$b$}
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}\refstepcounter{equation}
\text{Heat addition:}   && 
    \xi = 0,  &&
    \sigma = T^\prime/\bar{T},        &&\tag{\theequation $a$-$b$}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose you want the equation numbers on the right side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use my `\Cen` macro, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}a-b}
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Gas injection:}    &
&\Cen{4}{\xi = Y_i,}  &
&\Cen{6}{\sigma = \left( \frac{\bar{s}_{\mathrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi,} &&
\\[1ex]
&\text{Heat addition:}   &
&\Cen{4}{\xi = 0,}  &
&\Cen{6}{\sigma = T^\prime/\bar{T},} &&
\end{flalign}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd also consider a standard alignment:

```latex
\begingroup\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}a-b}
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Gas injection:}    &
\xi &= Y_i,  &
\sigma &= \left( \frac{\bar{s}_{\mathrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi, &&
\\[1ex]
&\text{Heat addition:}   &
\xi &= 0,  &
\sigma &= T^\prime/\bar{T}, &&
\end{flalign}
\endgroup
```

[image]

You can label the equations separately, but you have to explicitly give the subequation letter. I also implemented math mode for the subequation letters (although I'd not use it myself).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\let\extra@label\label
\newcounter{equationtemp}
\newcommand{\extralabel}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{equationtemp}{\value{equation}}%
  \renewcommand{\theequationtemp}{\arabic{equationtemp}$#1$}%
  \refstepcounter{equationtemp}%
  \extra@label{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}$a$-$b$}
\begin{flalign}
\label{first}
&\text{Gas injection:} &
&\Cen{4}{\xi = Y_i,}  \extralabel{a}{one} &
&\Cen{6}{\sigma = \left( \frac{\bar{s}_{\mathrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi,}
  \extralabel{b}{two} &&
\\[1ex]
\label{second}
&\text{Heat addition:} &
&\Cen{4}{\xi = 0,} \extralabel{a}{three} &
&\Cen{6}{\sigma = T^\prime/\bar{T},} \extralabel{b}{four} &&
\end{flalign}
\endgroup

\ref{one} and \ref{two}; \ref{three} and \ref{four}; \ref{first} and \ref{second}.

\eqref{one} and \eqref{two}; \eqref{three} and \eqref{four}; \eqref{first} and \eqref{second}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this! how can I keep the same formatting for the equations (i.e. lettering in italic)?

Comment: also forgot to mention this in my question - using your solution, how can I label each of the equations independently?

Comment: Thanks for the edits! One last query - any chance of being able to reference as well as individual eqtns 1a, 1b, reference (1a-b)?

Comment: @jrjrjr Just use the ordinary `\label` in addition to `\extralabel`. I edited the code to show the usage.

Comment: that works - unfortunately the \extralabel macro isn't working in my other latex file. Probably not compatible with something I've loaded, the error says "Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }"

Comment: @jrjrjr With hyperref it’s much more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

I propose these solutions, based on a normal `align` environment, within a `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` which *locally* sets the `fleqn` option of `amsmath`, and a custom tag form with the help of `mathtools`.

There two variants: either the columns are aligned on the `=` sign, or the left column alone is so aligned, but the right column is centred (in the left column, the widths of each row  are too close, and centring them doesn't look very nice, but you can do it if you prefer). Centring is obtained with the `eqparbox` package, which uses a system of tags, so that boxes sharing the same tag have the width of the largest natural width in the family.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,default, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newtagform{a-b}{(}{a-b)}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\usetagform{a-b}
\begin{align}%\
 & \text{Gas injection:} &
    \xi & = Y_i, & \sigma & = \left( \dfrac{\bar{s}_{\textrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi, \\[0.5ex]
 & \text{Heat addition:} & \xi & = 0, & \sigma & = T^\prime/\bar{T},
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\bigskip

\begin{fleqn}
\usetagform{a-b}
\begin{align}%\
 & \text{Gas injection:} & \xi &= Y_i, & &
 \eqmathbox[R]{\sigma = \left( \dfrac{\bar{s}_{\textrm{air}}-\bar{s}_{i}}{\bar{c}_p} \right)\xi}, \\[0.5ex]
 & \text{Heat addition:} & \xi &= 0, & & \eqmathbox[R]{\sigma = T^\prime/\bar{T},}
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this suggestion!