# Unable to properly align equations

Tags: align, ieeetran, columns, ampersand, eqnarray

I've got a system of equations that I can't seem to be able to properly aligned. I've attached an image of how I want to align the equations - all the red points aligned together, and all the blue together.

The code I have currently is below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
ik\widehat{\text{v}_{{x}}} + \frac{d\widehat{\text{v}_{z}}}{dz}={}&0, 
\label{massLin} \\
\left[\widehat{T} - St\, \widehat{\phi} \right]\sigma + \widehat{\text{v}_{{z}}} ={}& \left(-k^2 + \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\right)\widehat{T},
\label{HeatLin} \\
\bigg[\widehat{S} - \frac{\rho_{\text{s}}}{\rho_{\text{l}}}\bigg(\mathcal{L}  + \frac{1}{2}+   z\bigg)\widehat{\phi}{}& \bigg]\sigma + \widehat{\text{v}_{{z}}} \nonumber \\ = \tau {}& \left(-k^2 + \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\right)\widehat{S},
\label{saltLine} \\
\sigma\widehat{\text{v}_{{x}}} = -ik\widehat{P} + Pr {}& \left(-k^2 + \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\right)\widehat{\text{v}_{{x}}}, 
\label{vxLin} \\
\sigma\widehat{\text{v}_{{z}}} = -\frac{d\widehat{P}}{dz} + Pr{}&\left(-k^2 + \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\right)\widehat{\text{v}_{{z}}}  \nonumber  \\
+Pr\,Ra_{\text{T}}\bigg(1+\frac{\beta}{\Gamma \alpha}{}& \bigg)\widehat{T} + Pr\,{Ra}_{\phi}\,\widehat{\phi},
\label{vzLin} \\
\widehat{S} - \widehat{T} = 0, 
\label{LiquidusLin}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I just cannot seem to get this.
Any help is very appreciated. [image]

Comment: Hi, please can you add a complete minimal example to be compiled your code?

Comment: Have done so now

Comment: Do you know the alignat enviroment?

Comment: I've not come across that before?

Comment: You can use also flalign: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209645/aligning-equations-with-left-and-right-comment

Comment: It's going to be difficult to align all of these as you have indicated, since two lines have material that's wider than the "allowed" component of an aligned display.  The first line of (24) and the second line of (26) will need to be artificially adjusted using `\mathrlap` and `\mathllap` from the `\mathtools` package.  See the package documentation for instructions and examples.  The `alignat` environment is provided by `amsmath` and well documented in the user guide {`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: To align the red points as well as the blue ones, larger spaces in the equation will appear on some lines because the equations are not the same size.