# Aligning equality signs while using stack relations

Tags: align

I am working with an align environment and would like to add some hints at the equality signs by specifying the used equation number at some steps. However, if I do that the equality signs don't align anymore. Is there a way to get the equality signs to align instead of the whole stack relation? See below for a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test align equality}

  \begin{equation}\label{eq::ac}
    a=c
  \end{equation}

  \begin{align*}
    a &= b \\
    &\stackrel{(\ref{eq::ac})}{=} c
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overset text over equal sign in in an Align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40337/overset-text-over-equal-sign-in-in-an-align-environment) See also [Center a column in align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70365/82917)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it using the `\mathclap` command from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`), but I propose another solution without `\stackrel`, which looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test align equality}

  \begin{equation}\label{eq::ac}
    a=c
  \end{equation}

  \begin{align*}
    a &= b \\
    &\stackrel{\mathclap{\eqref{eq::ac}}}{=} c
  \end{align*}

  \begin{align*}
    a &= b \\
    &= c\rlap{ \qquad by \eqref{eq::ac}}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please use `\mathclap`... `:-)`

Comment: @campa: it is not needed: \eqref is typeset in text mode.

Comment: Yeah, but the scaling is wrong.

Comment: Oh! yes. I forgot this point. I'll fix that within seconds. Thanks for pointing it!